# MobileFirst Foundation Platform 6.3 - Replacing Cordova with Crosswalk

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to replace Cordova with Crosswalk in my MobileFirst Foundation Platform 6.3 project:

https://crosswalk-project.org/

But I can't seem to find any articles or documentation on how I would do this, did anyone try to do this before?

Comment: given Idan's comment, I suggest you open another question with some details about your project, asking about performance improvements... we may be able to give some suggestions.

Comment: I definitely will, I'm doing my research first and applying all the knowledge I'm acquiring and then I will open another question with specific cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find such article, because it is not possible at this time to replace the Cordova that is used within a Worklight/MobileFirst Platform application with the offering by the Crosswalk project.

The current relationship between the two entities is too tight right now.
You will need to continue and use what that is offered by MFP v6.3.

That said, feel free to suggest product enhancements: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got any alternative ideas on how I can improve my HTML5 app performance?

Comment: That's a big generic... where is the problem? startup? runtime? certain actions? do you have any benchmarks? tried using native components? are you using any frameworks?

Comment: MFP 7.1 is out and still it is not possible to use crosswalk with hybrid projects.

Comment: None said it will be. It is still not possible also in 7.1

Comment: @IdanAdar - Its possible to do with MobileFirst 8.0 to use Crosswalk in MFP 8.0 project.

Comment: Correct, this has been made possible starting MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

Comment: Thanks Adar. I found this article  Will give a try . Thanks https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/cordova-apps/#crosswalk-support-for-android